# How to directly link a SharePoint list to an existing table in MS access?

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

Looked around quite a bit before posting this - I just can't seem to get this seemingly very simple question answered (I think I missing something!)

From within MS Access 2007 I have several related tables that deal with inventory of products. I simply want to export that table data into a SharePoint List (or Lists), and link them. Users will generally just use the SP lists in order to search, view, and sometimes modify the data (i.e. mark a product as exhausted). For our work group this is preferential to opening MS Access repetitively.

The problem I'm having is that the linking features within Access don't make sense to me! I seem to be missing something fundamental here, despite reading over the MS documentation and various sources.

One can export a table, but there is no linkage between the created list and the original table. Changes made on the SP list will not be reflected in the original table which makes this a lot less useful?

One can import a list, but that linked table that is generated is NOT the original data table that I started with (the new, generated SP-linked table is a different entity than the original table. Updates to that new SP-linked table are not reflected in any original table that I had). This method seems very backwards, as you ought to have your relational DB setup correctly before attempting to make SP lists that surface that data. It seems backwards to me to make SP lists that are then wedged into an existing DB without any consideration to the existing DB structure?

So - I think that there is something fundamental that I'm missing here. It would seem that one ought to be able to just use SP to surface/provide views/editing of existing Access tables.

Isn't there just a simple way to have a SP list directly linked to an existing Access table, so that changes in the SP list are reflected in the original Access table?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution you're looking for is the ability to "Publish" an Access DB to a SharePoint site. If you're using SharePoint 2007, the published copy will be read-only in SharePoint but users can still do everything else you described.

Details on this type of Publish are in the Office Help here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Publish-a-database-to-a-SharePoint-site-8287ed04-9c65-46c4-bbdb-c965c56b018c

To quote from it:

> 1. Click the Microsoft Office Button  Office button image , point to
>      Publish , and then click Document Management Server.
> 2. Type the URL of
>      the SharePoint site where you want to publish the database. If you
>      used the same location the last time you opened Access, the database
>      appears in the Publish to Web Server dialog box.
>      `NOTE: This option is available only if your database is saved in Office Access 2007 format.`
> 3. Select the library, such as a document library, where you
>      want to publish the database, and then click Open.
> 4. In the Name box,
>      type a file name for your database.
> 5. Click Publish.

If you have SharePoint 2010 or newer, users in SharePoint can have full CRUD (Create, Read, Update & Delete) capabilities to both the data and even the DB design without having to touch Access once the DB has been published. This is described in more detail here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Build-and-publish-an-Access-database-to-SharePoint-e68bf007-410c-43b2-bf21-322ddbcf5411

The steps to do so are simply:

1. Open the Access file
2. Click 'Save and Publish' in the File menu
3. Choose 'Publish to Access Services' under the Publish heading
4. Specify the URL to the SharePoint site you wish to publish it to

Comment: Thank you - although this wasn't exactly what I was looking for, it led me down the right path eventually.

Comment: I ended up with the following fixit steps: 1) finish current database 2) export all tables to a SP site 3) create new .accdb 4) import/link those tables to the new .accdb. In this manner I avoided having to copy/paste/update query the data. Seems to have given a good point to start from. My mistake was thinking I needed both regular tables and linked tables in the same DB, which is of course wrong. I just needed the linked tables and will build queries,etc off of that